# When to send response to client socket

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I've a simple question I couldn't solve by myself searching on Google, hope you can help me.

I'm writing a network application server and using epoll/kqueue for handling connections.

Should I send response to client socket as soon as I get the request and process it, or should I add client socket to epoll/kqueue monitoring and send response when it tells me it's available for writing operation?

Ex. (pseudo-code). Should I do this:

```
while(true) {
    epoll/kqueue check for events

    if(triggered event is server listening socket) {

        accept() new socket
        add it to epoll/kqueue monitoring

    } else //triggered event is client socket

        if(event is read) {
            recv() request and process it
            send() response //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        } else
            ...
}
```

Or this:

```
while(true) {
    epoll/kqueue check for events

    if(triggered event is server listening socket) {

        accept() new socket
        add it to epoll/kqueue monitoring

    } else //triggered event is client socket

        if(event is read) {
            recv() request and process it
            add client socket to epoll/kqueue monitoring
        } else if(event is write)
            send() previously processed response //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        else
            ...
}
```

In previous simple sockets experiments I did, responses where sent as soon as request where processed just like first pseudo-code shows, but I don't know if it works the same in real environment because of latency, browser connections number limit, etc.

So it makes me sense to do it as in second pseudo-code, but I don't know if having to wait for epoll/kqueue tell client socket is ready for writing operation would add some significant latency in TCP communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I send response to client socket as soon as I get the request and process it

Yes.

> or should I add client socket to epoll/kqueue monitoring and send response when it tells me it's available for writing operation?

No. That operation is for when `send()` has return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.` At that point the socket send buffer is full, so you have to queue what remains of the send and try it again when `epoll()` tells you the socket is writable. You should only be interested in the 'writable' event when this has occurred on a socket. And when you retry, as long as you can now complete the send, you should remove interest in writablility for that socket.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can send the response to the client as soon as when you complete the client request. But one thing before sending the response you can check the status of client.So that you can ensure whether the client is in a ready state or not

Comment: So in other words a bit of both? What exactly is your answer?

Comment: Yes.That is the best way.You can check the status of send response by using the return error code. 4xx: Client Error

Comment: *Which* is the best? That's what he's asking. When you're asked what you mean, 'yes' is not an acceptable answer. You're having a bob each way here. Unless by 'check the status of client' you mean something other than using epoll() to check writability, in which case you're talking about something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sree I can't understand how HTTP 4xx errors can help deciding when server should send response. Furthermore, my question is related to socket programming level (I removed HTTP server mentions). At this point, isn't "check the status of client" what epoll/kqueue already does before returning an event for read/write?